# how to do that MacOS file icon overlay (like parallels desktop) without FinderSync?

Tags: macos, icons, findersync

Like this:
[Parallels Desktop can do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgsWA.png)

In this picture, we can see an exe(windows PE) file's icon has been shown in finder, but I also realized that PD just change the preview picture, the real icon not change file associations to itself.

I have make a FinderSync plugin, but it works bad, too slow with XPC communication.

Comment: You sure the OS version is not before `10.11` (El Capitan)? Because before this release, you could "hack" the OS code to display any overlay you want.

Comment: sure, PD is working on my MBP with HighSierra(10.13)...and my findersync icon overlay became slow in 10.13.